# Debugging autoencoder training (loss is low but reconstructed image is all black)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, autoencoder

I am implementing a (variational) autoencoder (VAE) in Keras following [this guide](https://keras.io/examples/generative/vae/).

The VAE reads data from `topomaps` folder and labels from `labels` folder. They both contain `.npy` files, [which are essentially numpy arrays stored on disk](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.format.html).

I split data set into 80% training data and 20% test data. Specifically:

- `x_train` shape is `(245760, 40, 40, 1)`
- `y_train` shape is `(245760,)`
- `x_test` shape is `(61440, 40, 40, 1)`
- `y_test` shape is `(61440,)`

Unfortunately even though the (training) `loss` and `val_loss` are pretty low (`2.9246e-04` and `-4.8249e-04`, respectively), if I visually check the "reconstruction skills" of my VAE, I can notice they are poor since reconstructed image is not similar at all to the original one:

[image: original]

[image: reconstructed]

I ran the demo using this configuration:

- `latent_dim=25`. This value must not be changed
- `epochs=2`
- `batch_size=512`
- `optimizer=Adam()`
- `learning_rate=0.001`

I know `epochs` is very small, but it is only a demo. I aim to enlarge it when I figure out why my VAE won't work even though loss is very low.

This is the run output:

```
Epoch 1/2
2023-08-30 11:35:49.408811: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/custom_graph_optimizer_registry.cc:114] Plugin optimizer for device_type GPU is enabled.
384/384 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 60.0042 - reconstruction_loss: 11.0072 - kl_loss: 0.09892023-08-30 11:38:40.538661: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/custom_graph_optimizer_registry.cc:114] Plugin optimizer for device_type GPU is enabled.
384/384 [==============================] - 190s 492ms/step - loss: 59.8772 - reconstruction_loss: 11.0072 - kl_loss: 0.0989 - val_loss: 5.5495e-04 - val_reconstruction_loss: 5.4875e-04 - val_kl_loss: 6.1989e-06
Epoch 2/2
384/384 [==============================] - 188s 490ms/step - loss: 3.0879e-04 - reconstruction_loss: 3.0472e-04 - kl_loss: 1.5222e-06 - val_loss: 3.4318e-04 - val_reconstruction_loss: 3.4303e-04 - val_kl_loss: 1.4901e-07
2023-08-30 11:42:17.049 Python[2419:58392] +[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction
2023-08-30 11:42:26.493 Python[2419:58392] +[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction
2023-08-30 11:42:37.200 Python[2419:58392] +[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction
2023-08-30 11:42:41.800433: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/custom_graph_optimizer_registry.cc:114] Plugin optimizer for device_type GPU is enabled.
1920/1920 [==============================] - 29s 15ms/step
2023-08-30 11:43:16.276 Python[2419:58392] +[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Learning curve:

[image: loss learning curve]

These are three model classes:

```
class VAE(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, encoder, decoder, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.encoder = encoder
        self.decoder = decoder
        self.total_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="total_loss")
        self.reconstruction_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="reconstruction_loss")
        self.kl_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="kl_loss")

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
        _, _, z = self.encoder(inputs)
        outputs = self.decoder(z)
        return outputs

    @property
    def metrics(self):
        return [
            self.total_loss_tracker,
            self.reconstruction_loss_tracker,
            self.kl_loss_tracker,
        ]

    def train_step(self, data):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            # Forward pass
            z_mean, z_log_var, z = self.encoder(data)
            reconstruction = self.decoder(z)

            # Compute losses
            reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(
                tf.reduce_sum(
                    keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(data, reconstruction), axis=(1, 2)
                )
            )
            kl_loss = -0.5 * (1 + z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var))
            kl_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(kl_loss, axis=1))
            total_loss = reconstruction_loss + kl_loss

        # Compute gradient
        grads = tape.gradient(total_loss, self.trainable_weights)

        # Update weights
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.trainable_weights))

        # Update my own metrics
        self.total_loss_tracker.update_state(total_loss)
        self.reconstruction_loss_tracker.update_state(reconstruction_loss)
        self.kl_loss_tracker.update_state(kl_loss)

        return {
            "loss": self.total_loss_tracker.result(),
            "reconstruction_loss": self.reconstruction_loss_tracker.result(),
            "kl_loss": self.kl_loss_tracker.result(),
        }

    def test_step(self, data):
        # Forward pass
        z_mean, z_log_var, z = self.encoder(data)
        reconstruction = self.decoder(z)

        # Compute losses
        reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(
            tf.reduce_sum(
                keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(data, reconstruction), axis=(1, 2)
            )
        )
        kl_loss = -0.5 * (1 + z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var))
        kl_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(kl_loss, axis=1))
        total_loss = reconstruction_loss + kl_loss

        # Update my own metrics
        self.total_loss_tracker.update_state(total_loss)
        self.reconstruction_loss_tracker.update_state(reconstruction_loss)
        self.kl_loss_tracker.update_state(kl_loss)

        return {
            "loss": self.total_loss_tracker.result(),
            "reconstruction_loss": self.reconstruction_loss_tracker.result(),
            "kl_loss": self.kl_loss_tracker.result(),
        }


class Encoder(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, latent_dimension, input_shape):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()
        self.latent_dim = latent_dimension
        self.conv_block1 = keras.Sequential([
            layers.Input(shape=input_shape),
            layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same"),
            layers.BatchNormalization()
        ])
        self.conv_block2 = keras.Sequential([
            layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same"),
            layers.BatchNormalization()
        ])
        self.conv_block3 = keras.Sequential([
            layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same"),
            layers.BatchNormalization()
        ])
        self.flatten = layers.Flatten()
        self.dense = layers.Dense(units=100, activation="relu")
        self.z_mean = layers.Dense(latent_dimension, name="z_mean")
        self.z_log_var = layers.Dense(latent_dimension, name="z_log_var")
        self.sampling = sample

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
        x = self.conv_block1(inputs)
        x = self.conv_block2(x)
        x = self.conv_block3(x)
        x = self.flatten(x)
        x = self.dense(x)
        z_mean = self.z_mean(x)
        z_log_var = self.z_log_var(x)
        z = self.sampling(z_mean, z_log_var)
        return z_mean, z_log_var, z


class Decoder(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, latent_dimension):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()
        self.latent_dim = latent_dimension
        self.dense1 = keras.Sequential([
            layers.Dense(units=100, activation="relu"),
            layers.BatchNormalization()
        ])
        self.dense2 = keras.Sequential([
            layers.Dense(units=1024, activation="relu"),
            layers.BatchNormalization()
        ])
        self.dense3 = keras.Sequential([
            layers.Dense(units=4096, activation="relu"),
            layers.BatchNormalization()
        ])
        self.reshape = layers.Reshape((4, 4, 256))
        self.deconv1 = keras.Sequential([
            layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=256, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same"),
            layers.BatchNormalization()
        ])
        self.deconv2 = keras.Sequential([
            layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", strides=1, padding="same"),
            layers.BatchNormalization()
        ])
        self.deconv3 = keras.Sequential([
            layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="valid"),
            layers.BatchNormalization()
        ])
        self.deconv4 = keras.Sequential([
            layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", strides=1, padding="valid"),
            layers.BatchNormalization()
        ])
        self.deconv5 = keras.Sequential([
            layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="valid"),
            layers.BatchNormalization()
        ])
        self.deconv6 = layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=1, kernel_size=2, activation="sigmoid", padding="valid")

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
        x = self.dense1(inputs)
        x = self.dense2(x)
        x = self.dense3(x)
        x = self.reshape(x)
        x = self.deconv1(x)
        x = self.deconv2(x)
        x = self.deconv3(x)
        x = self.deconv4(x)
        x = self.deconv5(x)
        decoder_outputs = self.deconv6(x)
        return decoder_outputs
```

Note that the implementation of the VAE belongs to the guide I already posted.

This is the main function:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Load data
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = load_data("topomaps", "labels", 0.2)

    # Expand dimensions to (None, 40, 40, 1)
    x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, -1)
    x_test = np.expand_dims(x_test, -1)

    # Print data shapes
    print("x_train shape:", x_train.shape)
    print("y_train shape:", y_train.shape)
    print("x_test shape:", x_test.shape)
    print("y_test shape:", y_test.shape)

    # Normalize the data
    x_train = x_train.astype("float32") / 255.0
    x_test = x_test.astype("float32") / 255.0

    # Compiling the VAE
    latent_dimension = 25  # Do not change
    encoder = Encoder(latent_dimension, (40, 40, 1))
    decoder = Decoder(latent_dimension)
    vae = VAE(encoder, decoder)
    vae.compile(Adam(learning_rate=0.001))

    # Training
    x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(x_train, y_train, test_size=0.2)
    print("x_val shape:", x_val.shape)
    print("y_val shape:", y_val.shape)
    epochs = 2
    batch_size = 512
    history = vae.fit(x_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_data=(x_val,))

    # Plot learning curves
    plot_metric(history, "loss")

    # Check reconstruction skills against a random test sample
    image_index = 5
    plt.title(f"Original image {image_index}")
    original_image = x_test[image_index]
    plt.imshow(original_image, cmap="gray")
    plt.show()

    plt.title(f"Reconstructed image {image_index}, latent_dim = {latent_dimension}, epochs = {epochs}, "
              f"batch_size = {batch_size}")
    x_test_reconstructed = vae.predict(x_test)
    reconstructed_image = x_test_reconstructed[image_index]
    plt.imshow(reconstructed_image, cmap="gray")
    plt.show()
```

These are some functions I used:

```
def load_data(topomaps_folder: str, labels_folder: str, test_size):
    x, y = _create_dataset(topomaps_folder, labels_folder)
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=test_size)
    return x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test

def _create_dataset(topomaps_folder, labels_folder):
    topomaps_files = os.listdir(topomaps_folder)
    labels_files = os.listdir(labels_folder)
    topomaps_files.sort()
    labels_files.sort()
    x = []
    y = []
    n_files = len(topomaps_files)
    for topomaps_file, labels_file in tqdm(zip(topomaps_files, labels_files), total=n_files, desc="Loading data set"):
        topomaps_array = np.load(f"{topomaps_folder}/{topomaps_file}")
        labels_array = np.load(f"{labels_folder}/{labels_file}")
        if topomaps_array.shape[0] != labels_array.shape[0]:
            raise Exception("Shapes must be equal")
        for i in range(topomaps_array.shape[0]):
            x.append(topomaps_array[i])
            y.append(labels_array[i])
    x = np.array(x)
    y = np.array(y)
    return x, y

def sample(z_mean, z_log_var):
    batch = tf.shape(z_mean)[0]
    dim = tf.shape(z_mean)[1]
    epsilon = tf.random.normal(shape=(batch, dim))
    stddev = tf.exp(0.5 * z_log_var)
    return z_mean + stddev * epsilon

def plot_metric(history, metric):
    plt.plot(history.history[metric])
    plt.plot(history.history['val_' + metric])
    plt.title(metric)
    plt.ylabel(metric)
    plt.xlabel('epoch')
    plt.legend(['train', 'validation'])
    plt.show()
```

**EDIT**

**- Could you try with much lower training set to see if it overfits and reconstructs a known image?** Okay, this is what I did in `main` function

```
# Reduce DS size
x_train = x_train[:500]
y_train = y_train[:500]
x_test = x_test[:500]
y_test = y_test[:500]
```

This is what I get:

[image: original]

[image: reconstructed]

and learning curve is:

[image: curve]

If I run the same configuration but setting `epochs=100` I get:

[image: original]

[image: reconstructed]

and loss:

[image: loss]

**- Not sure if you did it...but did you convert your output back to a non-normalized value when plotting?** This is what I have done:

```
plt.title(f"Reconstructed image {image_index}, latent_dim = {latent_dimension}, epochs = {epochs}, "
          f"batch_size = {batch_size}")
x_test_reconstructed = vae.predict(x_test)
reconstructed_image = x_test_reconstructed[image_index]
reconstructed_image = reconstructed_image * 255
plt.imshow(reconstructed_image, cmap="gray")
plt.show()
```

But I still get:

[image: rec]

**- What does the loss graph look like when the batch size is 4 and learning rate is 0.0002 for 100 epochs?** Reconstructed image is all black and loss curve is:

[image: loss]

Comment: Could you try with much lower training set to see if it overfits and reconstructs a known image?

Comment: Not sure if you did it...but did you convert your output back to a non-normalized value when plotting?

Comment: @doneforaiur I've just edited my post. Check it out

Comment: @JasonChia I edited my post. Please check it out

Comment: Length of the dataset is 500 but your batch size is 512. Try fiddleing with lower batch size first then adjust learning rate. Can't really give you a straight answer because I can't run your code but the code looks good to me; I suspect the parameters are not right. (Altough I'm not sure why your second image is so "symmetrical", hmm.)

Comment: @doneforaiur Same problem even though I reduce batch size to 128 (when data set size is 500)

Comment: What does the loss graph look like when the batch size is 4 and learning rate is 0.0002 for 100 epochs? If the training time is an issue, you can even try 4 samples from the main dataset as we only trying to overfit at the moment.

Comment: @doneforaiur I edited my post please check it out

Comment: I am trying to wrap my head around your model..but typical VAE is Encoder.shape == Decoder.shape. The encoder and decoder should be the same no ?

Comment: @JasonChia The encoder accepts (None, 40, 40, 1) shaped data while the decoder outputs (None, 40, 40, 1) shaped data

Comment: I might be wrong but the model doesnt look right to me. Can you try the MNIST dataset with your VAE? if you are still getting rubbish...then definitely something is wrong with the implementation of your VAE.

Comment: @JasonChia Why it does not look right?

Comment: @JasonChia VAE implementation belongs to the official Keras guide.

Comment: Yes. The keras guide uses a single dense layer then reshape. You have 3 dense layers before the reshape. Hence the decoder! = encoder.

Comment: @JasonChia I am getting the same result even if I remove those additional dense layers in Decoder.

Comment: Can you add a single raw png. I'll try to run on my vae implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem concerned the data normalization.

```
x_train = (x_train - np.min(x_train)) / (np.max(x_train) - np.min(x_train))
```

and

```
x_test = (x_test - np.min(x_test)) / (np.max(x_test) - np.min(x_test))
```

should resolve the issue.

Comment: So you solved your problem? Its a little bit odd if your images were initially 0-255 pixel values. since /255 would normalize it as well.

Comment: @JasonChia Reconstruction skills are still poor but at least loss is high and reconstructed image is not total black. I noticed that my images were not 0-255 initially

Answer (score 0):

I ran on my implementation with no problems. I ran on a 'copy' of the VAE tutorial and got the following results after 1 epoch:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class Sampling(layers.Layer):
    def call(self, inputs):
        z_mean, z_log_var = inputs
        batch = tf.shape(z_mean)[0]
        dim = tf.shape(z_mean)[1]
        epsilon = tf.random.normal(shape=(batch, dim))
        return z_mean + tf.exp(0.5 * z_log_var) * epsilon


latent_dim = 25

encoder_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(40, 40, 1))
x = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")(encoder_inputs)
x = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")(x)
x = layers.Flatten()(x)
x = layers.Dense(16, activation="relu")(x)
z_mean = layers.Dense(latent_dim, name="z_mean")(x)
z_log_var = layers.Dense(latent_dim, name="z_log_var")(x)
z = Sampling()([z_mean, z_log_var])
encoder = keras.Model(encoder_inputs, [z_mean, z_log_var, z], name="encoder")
encoder.summary()



latent_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
x = layers.Dense(6400, activation="relu")(latent_inputs)
x = layers.Reshape((10,10,64))(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")(x)
decoder_outputs = layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, 3, activation="sigmoid", padding="same")(x)
decoder = keras.Model(latent_inputs, decoder_outputs, name="decoder")
decoder.summary()


class VAE(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, encoder, decoder, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.encoder = encoder
        self.decoder = decoder
        self.total_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="total_loss")
        self.reconstruction_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(
            name="reconstruction_loss"
        )
        self.kl_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="kl_loss")

    @property
    def metrics(self):
        return [
            self.total_loss_tracker,
            self.reconstruction_loss_tracker,
            self.kl_loss_tracker,
        ]

    def train_step(self, data):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            z_mean, z_log_var, z = self.encoder(data)
            reconstruction = self.decoder(z)
            reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(
                tf.reduce_sum(
                    keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(data, reconstruction), axis=(1, 2)
                )
            )
            kl_loss = -0.5 * (1 + z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var))
            kl_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(kl_loss, axis=1))
            total_loss = reconstruction_loss + kl_loss
        grads = tape.gradient(total_loss, self.trainable_weights)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.trainable_weights))
        self.total_loss_tracker.update_state(total_loss)
        self.reconstruction_loss_tracker.update_state(reconstruction_loss)
        self.kl_loss_tracker.update_state(kl_loss)
        return {
            "loss": self.total_loss_tracker.result(),
            "reconstruction_loss": self.reconstruction_loss_tracker.result(),
            "kl_loss": self.kl_loss_tracker.result(),
        }

def create_data():
    x_train = []
    data = cv2.imread("IMAGE",0) #used a screen clipping since I do not have your data source
    data = cv2.resize(data, (40,40), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA) # resize it to the same 40x40 limit 
    gaussian = np.random.normal(0, 0.2, (data.shape[0],data.shape[1])) #add noise for realism
    
    x_train = np.array([data]*1000) #duplicated with random noise 1000x
    x_train[:] = x_train[:]+gaussian
    x_test = x_train
    return x_train, x_test, data
    
x_train,x_test , data = create_data()
x = x_train
x = np.expand_dims(x,-1).astype("float32") / 255



vae = VAE(encoder, decoder)
vae.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam())
vae.fit(x, epochs=1, batch_size=8)
data_input = np.expand_dims(data,-1).astype("float32")/255
print(data_input.shape)
latent = vae.encoder.predict(x)
print(latent)
output = vae.decoder.predict(latent[0])
digit = output[0]
plt.figure("Source")
plt.imshow(data,cmap="gray")
plt.figure("output")
plt.imshow(digit,cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

I didn't have your data so I could not check if your data loader is doing any mistakes. You probably want to check your call functions on your autoencoder and decoder but following the tutorial code I did not find your issue.

I would suggest a comprehensive debug with your data:

1. Check data inputs, structures, shapes etc. (sanity tests are good)
2. Try removing the test validation.
3. Ensure model works on known dataset I.e Mnist. Try calling your VAE on the MNIST data set and if it doesnt work then something is wrong here.

Unless I have some samples of your input data there really is no way to properly debug your code. I highly suspect the data inputs because the model construction code looks fine.

[image: Source image]

[image: VAE output]

Comment: Thank you for your effort. If you need my source data, you can find it here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AImA7TV0laMU1R0nnNyDJ5oeyXTa9-ny/view?usp=share_link

Comment: I tried to use your code with my source data but unfortunately I am still getting the "black" reconstructed image. Can you further help me using the data I shared?